# How do I implement a header source switch?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

As the title says, the IDE I am using is Visual Studio 2012 Express.

MS Dev 2012 Express does not support ad-ins (like PhatStudio) or macros.  Is there any other way of doing this other than using the goto definition function in the right click menu.

I would like a method which allows me to use a keyboard shortcut (like in PhatStudio or VisualAssist).

Comment: When the go to defintion doesn't work (I think templates are the problem), I go to "open the containing folder"  the header tab and select the source (because my projects have headers and source with the same name in the same folder). It's not a very direct method, I know!

Comment: Well, yes admittedly that would work but I want a key board shortcut like I used to have with VisualAssist.  Have update the question to reflect that.

Comment: Built in shortcuts for jumping to declaration definition and switch betwee open tabs is F12, ctrl+alt+f12, ctrl+tab

Comment: True but that does not do header to source switch, just definition and declaration.